# Show that $H$ is not normal in $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H=\{(1), (1,2)(3,4)\}$ in $A_4$. Show $H$ is not Normal in $A_4$ using the definition of normal.

So I know that $A_4$ is the alternating group on $4$ letters, but I don't understand what that means. Can someone please explain? I also know that for a subgroup $H$ of $G$ to be normal, its left and right cosets must coincide. ie: $aH=Ha$. From here, how do I use this definition to prove that $A_4$ is not normal?

My plan was this: 
the left cosets are:

$1+H= \{(2),(2,3),(4,5)\}$ $\leftarrow$ Can you have $5$ in $A_4$, or would it be $0$ or $1$???

$2+H= \{(3),(3,4)\}$

$3+H= \{(4)\}$,

I think my main issue is that I do not understand what it means for something to be an "alternating group on 4 letters". Also, am I on the right track for trying to see if the cosets coincide?

Comment: There are some misunderstandings here. First of all, $H$ (at least in the way you wrote it) is not a group. I suspect that it was meant to be $\{(1),(1,2)(3,4)\}$, but this is just a guess. Then there seems to be some confusion as to what the multiplication is in this situation (are you familiar with the symmetric group and permutations?).

Comment: Yes! I took another look and you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(1\;2\;3)\color{red}{(1\;2)(3\;4)}(1\;2\;3)^{-1}=(123)\color{red}{(12)(34)}(132)=(14)(23)\notin H$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** That's a blunder! The cosets are formed under group operations. In permutation group, composition *(or loosely, multiplication)* and **not addition** is the group operation.

Open the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group#Composition_of_permutations.E2.80.93the_group_product) to know how a composition is evaluated.

Comment: So rather than adding 1+H, 2+H etc to find the cosets, it would be multiplying: 0H,1H,2H,3H. would you multiply 4H as well, again, I am confused by exactly what it means for something to be "an alternating group on 4 letters". also, now that the question is changed im even more confused.

Comment: $aH$ is a coset if $a\in A_4$. Note that $0,1,2,3,4$ are **not** in $A_4$

Comment: so what is in A4?

Comment: I do not understand what A4 is.. I think that that is the main problem.

Comment: You should read, [Permutation groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group), then [Alternating group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group#Examples_S4_and_A4). I recommend [Gallian](http://libgen.org/search.php?req=contemporary+abstract+algebra&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def).